# Long-format Regression model refering to older measures?

Tags: r, regression

Imagine I have an experiment in which I take repeated measures to a group of individuals.
The following diagram represents the measures taken to each individual at each time.
[image]

The data could be stored on a wide format table, with one row for each individual.
ID x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4

Or it could also be stored in a more compact long format, like this:

ID T X Y

Where T would be 1, 2, 3 or 4. For the moment just leave it simple, T increments are always the same, 1 unit.

I've been seeing and using this long format to fit regression models with dummy variables.
I use to do it with R (with the syntax "Y ~ X*T" where T is a factor) but it can be done on many other programs in different ways.

In this situation you can find the relationship between each y and its corresponding x (for the same time).
It would be similar to say:

```
y1 = a1 + b1·X1
y2 = a2 + b2·X2
y3 = a3 + b3·X3
```

But you get more power because you analyze all the data together.
Usually I do it with lme4 in order to take into account the repeated measures.  But forget it for the moment.

My question is, **Is it possible to use the "long format" to find relationships such as this?**

```
y1 = a10 + a11·X1
y2 = a20 + a21·X1 + a22·X2
y3 = a30 + a31·X1 + a32·X2 + a33·X3
```

I mean, every "y" not only depends on the "x" in the same time but also in previous "x". (Kinda cumulative effect).

Or, Am I forced to use a wide format and create new variables instead?

I think the problem with the wide format is that we will lose the explicit dependency with T, the time. And I woulkd like to see how the outcome depends on it.
And I find it easier to work with long format.

If you want a very simple reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
ID <- rep(1:4,each=4)
XX <- round(runif(16),3)
TT <- rep(1:4, 4)
YY <- ave(XX*TT,ID, FUN = cumsum)
data.frame(ID,TT,XX, YY)

 ID TT    XX    YY
  1  1 0.266 0.266
  1  2 0.372 1.010
  1  3 0.573 2.729
  1  4 0.908 6.361
  2  1 0.202 0.202
  2  2 0.898 1.998
  2  3 0.945 4.833
  2  4 0.661 7.477
  3  1 0.629 0.629
  3  2 0.062 0.753
  3  3 0.206 1.371
  3  4 0.177 2.079
  4  1 0.687 0.687
  4  2 0.384 1.455
  4  3 0.770 3.765
  4  4 0.498 5.757
```

Any solution not relying on R is also welcome.